# Android: Set corner radius for RippleDrawable programmatically

Tags: android, android-drawable

I'm trying to create a segmented buttons control and I've used a single drawable for each of the segments.

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="?android:colorControlHighlight">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/search_filters_selected" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/search_filters_unselected" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="@color/search_filters_selected" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

Then, according to whether it's the first, last or in the middle, I set the corner radius to have rounded left corners, right corners or none, using `setCornerRadii`.

The problem is that I'm trying to show a ripple effect in the view, and I can't make it so that the ripple effect is bounded by the rounded corners, it's always drawn up to the original rectangle, [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVHcP.png)

I've tried setting the same corner radii to the mask of the RippleDrawable, or using 
`<item android:drawable="?android:selectableItemBackground" />` within a layer-list instead of a `<ripple>`, but the result is the same. Does anyone know how to make it so the ripple is bounded up to the new bounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution, if it's useful for anyone, it's to use a ripple without mask, but also with a set corner radius (any one, it will be updated later)

So I used

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="?android:colorControlHighlight">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#625505" />
            <corners android:radius="1dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/search_filters_selected" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="@color/search_filters_selected" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

and finally got it to work